# yarn install error：Failed to download Chromium

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

The Yarn install failed to download Chromium. Error is as follows:

```
D:\workspace\www\ant-design-mobile-pro
λ yarn
yarn install v1.12.3
//...
Directory: D:\\workspace\\www\\ant-design-mobile-pro\\node_modules\\puppeteer
Output:
ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r599821! Set \"PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD\" env variable to skip download.
{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.161.176:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1113:14)
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '172.217.161.176',
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 343.80s.
```

**Question：**
Can I download Chromium manually? I can download it from `https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/`,the question is: Where should I put it after dowloading it?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't intend to run the automated browser tests which depend upon Chromium, you can skip the install per the error message:

`export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true && yarn`

I've occasionally encountered this `yarn` install timeout recently as well, and no `cache clear` or other manipulation has seemed to resolve it.